# How to set up ssh access for multiple users on a compute engine vm on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to set up a cloud compute engine VM for multiple people to use. I would like to keep root access to myself and provide non-admin level privileges for other users. I wasn't able to create an organization with my original google account used for the VM.

To allow multiple people to access the VM I created a service account with the domain of my organization (ex: admin@organization.com) and I tried to transfer ownership of the VM and billing to the new account. When I opened the link with the original google account to do the setup wizard, my projects weren't listed.

I'm under the impression that it is a permissions issue but I'm not sure.
Once I've transferred the project to the organization service account I would like to create additional accounts (ex: guest@organization.com) and set up ssh access through those.

Quick note: I'm a student (big noob) and the organization is a society.

Answer (score 3):

To grant SSH access to VMs to users in your organization, enable [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin) feature in your project.And grant one of the following instance access roles.

1. [roles/compute.osLogin](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.osLogin), which does not grant administrator permissions on the VM.
2. [roles/compute.osAdminLogin](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.osAdminLogin), which grants administrator permissions.
3. If your VM instance uses a service account, then each user must be configured to have the [roles/iam.serviceAccountUser](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#the_serviceaccountuser_role) role on the service account. To learn how to add access for a user to a service account, see [Managing service account impersonation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts).

Take a look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access) article for more info.